# Dumping exception, how bad idea is to do this on production?

Tags: php, exception

I have been searching for a similar question here but found none.

What are the real disadventages of dumping exception backtrace on production server?
When there has been some unrecoverable error and an exception has been thrown, is this a bad idea to dump it to file for later debugging? By dumping i do not mean to serialize the exception object but things like stack trace, included files, memory usage, superglobals or local variables. I am aware that this might affect performance and/or security somehow but should I count only on my users feedback or dev tests?

Things like XDebug have really no place here because they mess so many things up an are really for development phase.

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Dump the data to a log file or send an email - that's fine.  Just be sure that the user does not see it.

Comment: Will a directory protected by htaccess do the job?

Comment: It should be written outside of DocumentRoot - /var/log/httpd/debug.log or something similar.

Comment: What if I decide to put this on shared hosting and have no access to /var/log? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Shared hosting should have account level resources outside of document root